# How to convert multiple documents using the Document Conversion service ina script bash?

Tags: ibm-watson, document-conversion

How can I convert more than one document using the [Document Conversion](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/document-conversion/) service.

I have between 50-100 MS Word and PDF documents that I want to convert using the  [`convert_document`](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/document-conversion-v1-experimental) API method?

For example, can you supply multiple .pdf or *.doc files like this?:

```
curl -u "username":"password" -X POST
-F "config={\"conversion_target\":\"ANSWER_UNITS\"};type=application/json" 
-F "file=@\*.doc;type=application/msword"
 "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/document-conversion-experimental/api/v1/convert_document"
```

That gives an error unfortunately: curl: (26) couldn't open file "*.doc".
I have also tried "file=@file1.doc,file2.doc,file3.doc" but that gives errors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service only accept one file at a time, but you can call it multiple time.

```
#!/bin/bash
USERNAME="<service-username>"
PASSWORD="<service-password>"
URL="https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/document-conversion-experimental/api/v1/convert_document"
DIRECTORY="/path/to/documents"
for doc in *.doc
do
  echo "Converting - $doc"
  curl -u "$USERNAME:$PASSWORD" \
  -F 'config={"conversion_target":"ANSWER_UNITS"};type=application/json' \
  -F "file=@$doc;type=application/pdf" "$URL"
done
```

Document Conversion [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/document-conversion/) and [API Reference](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/document-conversion/api/v1/).